# How can I use the development labeled file to make prediction and testing labeled file to validation?

Tags: python, validation, text-classification

I have a dataset containing three files, which are Training, development, and testing file, Each file is labeled with one class label such as "Sadness", each file has the same class label "Sadness", how can I use three files to employ a classification for text by machine learning algorithms? and can I evaluate the prediction for one class label?
how can I read three files and make training and make a prediction and evaluate predictions in Python?

Comment: "each file is labeled with one class label" -> do you mean that there is a single label of the whole file, or that the file contains several instances and each of them is labelled with "sadness" or not? Maybe you could give a short example of the kind of data you have?

Comment: @Erwan, Thx, I have a dataset for text classification to detect the emotion divided into four folders(Sadness, Joy, Fear, Anger), Each folder contain three files which are Training, development, and Testing, and Each file in any folder has one class label (not Binary) to detect one emotion such as “Sadness”, I want to detect the emotion by Machine Learning algorithm, How can I train the model? What files do I use for training (Training or development)?

and can I do validation for one class label on the machine learning!?

Comment: ok that's a bit clearer but does one file contain several instances/documents? For instance the file `training` in the folder `Sadness`, what does it contain? it could be many sentences which are all "sad" for example. But if it's a single document which is "sad" as a whole, then that's not enough data for ML.

Comment: @Erwan, Well, every file (emotion) contains many instances (tweets).
For example, the file training in the folder Sadness contains many tweets, but all of them are classified for one emotion (Sadness) and other file testing and development contain many instances and the class label is Sadness.

Comment: ok that's good then, I just wanted to make sure that you have a collection of instances for every class. Probably you will have to read the files and format each dataset (e.g. training) as a dataframe or array with two columns, one for the tweet and one of the class.

Comment: @Erwan, Tnx, Well, But, How can I deal with the development file!? Where can I use it

Comment: A development set can be used like a validation set, i.e. as a kind of "draft test set". The goal is to avoid using the real test set until the final testing stage, in order to avoid any data leakage. The dev set can be used for evaluating the performance when trying several different models, or doing feature selection or hyper-parameter tuning. It's optional: if you don't plan to do any of these things at all and you want to directly train a model and apply it on the test set, then you can either ignore the dev set or concatenate it with the training set.